# automount problems

Tags: automount

I have a Yosemite Mac Mini with performance problems. When looking at the disk activity with `opensnoop` I noticed that automount is performing tons of accesses as follows

```
  UID    PID COMM          FD PATH
    0   1124 automountd     4 /etc/auto_home
    0   1124 automountd     6 /etc/auto_home
    0  55536 od_user_homes   5 /System/Library/OpenDirectory/request-schema.plist
    0  55536 od_user_homes   7 /usr/libexec
    0  55536 od_user_homes   7 /usr/libexec
    0  55536 od_user_homes   7 /usr/libexec/od_user_homes
    0   1124 automountd     4 /etc/auto_home
    0   1124 automountd     6 /etc/auto_home
    0   1124 automountd     6 /usr/libexec/od_user_homes
  501    464 syncdefaultsd   4 /Users/corti/Library/SyncedPreferences/.dat01d0.559
    0   1124 automountd     6 /usr/libexec/od_user_homes
    0     58 opendirectoryd   9 /var/db/dslocal/nodes//Default/users/corti.plist
    0  55537 od_user_homes   5 /System/Library/OpenDirectory/request-schema.plist
    0  55537 od_user_homes   7 /usr/libexec
    0  55537 od_user_homes   7 /usr/libexec
    0  55537 od_user_homes   7 /usr/libexec/od_user_homes
    0     58 opendirectoryd   9 /var/db/dslocal/nodes//Default/users/corti.plist
    0  55538 od_user_homes   5 /System/Library/OpenDirectory/request-schema.plist
    0  55538 od_user_homes   7 /usr/libexec
    0  55538 od_user_homes   7 /usr/libexec/od_user_homes
    0  55539 od_user_homes   5 /System/Library/OpenDirectory/request-schema.plist
    0  55539 od_user_homes   7 /usr/libexec
    0  55539 od_user_homes   7 /usr/libexec
    0   1124 automountd     4 /etc/auto_home
    0   1124 automountd     6 /etc/auto_home
    0   1124 automountd     6 /usr/libexec/od_user_homes
    0  55540 od_user_homes   5 /System/Library/OpenDirectory/request-schema.plist
    0  55540 od_user_homes   7 /usr/libexec
    0  55540 od_user_homes   7 /usr/libexec
    0   1124 automountd     4 /etc/auto_home
    0   1124 automountd     6 /etc/auto_home
    0   1124 automountd     6 /usr/libexec/od_user_homes
    0  55541 od_user_homes   5 /System/Library/OpenDirectory/request-schema.plist
    0  55541 od_user_homes   7 /usr/libexec
    0  55541 od_user_homes   7 /usr/libexec
    0  55541 od_user_homes   7 /usr/libexec/od_user_homes
```

Hundreds of access per second. Is this normal? What could be wrong?

Comment: Please more fully describe your Open Directory networking setup: number of clients/servers & Mac OS X versions on each machine. How many volumes are being served?

Comment: @IconDaemon I have one single machine and never configured anything special. Where should I look?

Comment: If this is a stand-alone machine, then things are very odd. In System Preferences > Users & Groups > Login Options, click the **Network Account Server: Join** button. In the drop-down sheet, click the Open Directory Utility... button. Click the Lock icon and authenticate. Open and inspect each service. **Active Directory**: No Active Directory Domain should be defined; **LDAPv3**: Show options and there should be no configurations defined; **NIS** No Domain name should be defined. If you find any servers defined, delete them.

Comment: @IconDaemon Server dropdown is empty. The Directory Utility shows: AD (Forest automatic, and no domain), LDAP empty and NIS empty. As far as I know there are no directory servers that could be automatically discovered: it's a home network with private addresses.

Comment: Perhaps the file /System/Library/OpenDirectory/request-schema.plist is corrupted somehow. Try moving it out of its directory and restart. Yosemite may try to recreate it.

Comment: @IconDaemon Thanks, I'll try this evening when I'm home: moving the file makes a remote login (ARD or SSH) impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it was a combination of Dropbox and broken symlinks (see [opendirectoryd consumes 40% of CPU](https://superuser.com/q/350879/97396) and [opendirectoryd taking up 1/4 of the cpu and driving fans crazy on MacBook Air](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/33312/opendirectoryd-taking-up-1-4-of-the-cpu-and-driving-fans-crazy-on-macbook-air)).

I recently moved some old files from a Linux machine to my Mac Mini with around 10 broken symlinks to `/home/.../` (in a Dropbox synchronized directory). Dropbox was causing `opendirectoryd` to continuously trying to mount `/home/`.

I removed the broken links and the machine seems now stable.