# Opendirectoryd uses up to 85% CPU. My mac heats up at a high temperature

Tags: open-directory

I am using MacOs Hight Sierra version 10.13.6. For some time, the computer has been heating up to a high temperature and it may even shut down at times.

[image]After searching the web, I discovered that one of the causes could be an opendirectoryd process that uses up to 90% of the CPU. It's my first time using Mac, I don't know what to do.

Some solutions talk about symlinks but I don't even know how to find them.

thank you for helping me

Comment: could you check console.app for any related errors ? or just anything too repetitive ? Also see the disk tab. Is the disk being read or written with a high speed ?

Comment: I can check but I have already done it before and I couldn't detect the real problem. Thanks